# PHP Mysql Parse Error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, parsing

I'm using this Code, to insert the data which is sent with POST into my database.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO pending 
 (name, alter, mail, kd, steam, spiele)
 VALUES
 ('$_POST["name"]', '$_POST["alter"]', '$_POST["mail"]', '$_POST["kd"]', '$_POST["steam"]', '$_POST["spiele"]')");
```

but PHP keeps throwing the following error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /var/www/bewerben.php on line 34

I cant see the problem there, because i think the '"' is needed there?

Comment: Wrap the `$_POST` values in {} braces, and perform sanitation before you put them in your query, otherwise you will be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks

Comment: Yes, I know how to secure my Code from SQL Injection, but I just wanted that it works before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a bad quote ordering. You can use curly bracers, to escape the variables:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO pending 
 (name, alter, mail, kd, steam, spiele)
 VALUES
 ('{$_POST['name']}', '{$_POST['alter']}', '{$_POST['mail']}', '{$_POST['kd']}', '{$_POST['steam']}', '{$_POST['spiele']}')");
```

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> Complex (curly) syntax
>
> This isn't called complex because the syntax is complex, but because
>   it allows for the use of complex expressions.
>
> Any scalar variable, array element or object property with a string
>   representation can be included via this syntax. Simply write the
>   expression the same way as it would appear outside the string, and
>   then wrap it in { and }.

To further explain, we have two variables:

```
$fruit = 'Orange';
$sentence = "$fruits are my favorite fruit";
```

What I'm trying to get is: `Oranges are my favorite fruit`. However, this won't work. PHP will instead be looking for a variable called `$fruits`, and when it doesn't find it, it'll show an error.

So to complete the task properly, we have to wrap the variable in curly braces `{ }`:

```
$fruit = 'Orange';
$sentence = "{$fruit}s are my favorite fruit";
```

Great! Now PHP will know where the variable name ends and the string starts.

*P.S. I recommend using mysqli.*

*I'm not quite sure I have the rights to write this here, but I looked at your code & I noticed a problem:*

> You are using `mysql_*` which is deprecated since `PHP 5.5.0`.
>   This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in
>   the future.

Instead of `mysql_*` you can use `PDO` or `MySQLi`.

Here is a simple example of using `MySQLi`:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_init();
$mysqli->real_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
```

Then you can prepare your query:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("insert into table values(?, ?)");
```

Bind the params:

```
$stmt->bind_param("is", $param1, $param2);
```

We say that the first variable `$param1` is an `integer` and `$param2` is a `string`.

The last thing we need to do is to assign to those variables some values and execute the statement.

```
$param1 = 1;
$param2 = "somestring";
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap you `$_POST` variables in `{}` or escape double quotes in its' keys with `\`:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO pending 
(name, alter, mail, kd, steam, spiele)
VALUES
('{$_POST["name"]}', '{$_POST["alter"]}', '{$_POST["mail"]}', '{$_POST["kd"]}',    '{$_POST["steam"]}', '{$_POST["spiele"]}')");
```

Comment: You should explain what you did. :)

Comment: Next error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''})");\r' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '}' in /var/www/bewerben.php on line 34

Answer (score 0):

or you can try this :

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO pending 
 (name, alter, mail, kd, steam, spiele)
 VALUES
 ('".$_POST["name"]."', '".$_POST["alter"]."', '".$_POST["mail"]."', '".$_POST["kd"]', '".$_POST["steam"]."', '".$_POST["spiele"]."')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`INSERT INTO pending 
 (name, alter, mail, kd, steam, spiele)
 VALUES
 ($_POST["name"], $_POST["alter"], $_POST["mail"], $_POST["kd"], $_POST["steam"], $_POST["spiele"])`

**NEVER INSERT POSTED VALUES WITHOUT VALIDATION / SANITIZING INTO THE DB**

Read about SQL injection : http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a function so your code is more reusable?. It's always good to make a single place for reoccurring processes, like adding quotes to strings.

```
$sql   = "INSERT INTO pending SET
          name   = ".quote($_POST['name']).",
          alter  = ".quote($_POST['alter']).",
          mail   = ".quote($_POST['mail']).",
          kd     = ".quote($_POST['kd']).",
          steam  = ".quote($_POST['steam']).",
          spiele = ".quote($_POST['spiele']);

mysql_query($sql);

function quote($val) {
    return "'".$val."'";
}
```

Also, I prefer using the `SET colname = value`  method for sql, it makes for much more readable code.